# Literature on noncommutative rings

Tags: ring-theory, book-recommendation, noncommutative-algebra, noetherian

I am looking for books or notes about non commutative rings with with a maximum of data exposed without the help of modules (because I have many references which deal with the subject but modules are used very early in the theory!).

Comment: It might help if you explained why you want to avoid modules. They are a fairly natural way to view certain things.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have no explanation in fact. I'd like to know the most possible without modules...

Comment: But why? Surely, you must have some reason why you want this?

Comment: @Carrérond The fact that all of your references introduce modules early on should tell you something about this practice being worthwhile. Inexplicable avoidance of something sounds a lot like you are *afraid* of it. Why not give it a shot? Why discard some of the best texts in the topic for this requirement?

Comment: I think Atiyah-Macdonald (this is in the commutative world, obviously) say in their book that modules offer the right amount of "wiggle room" for the study of rings. That's worth pondering, I think. And as soon as you introduce ideals it's not much more work to generalize to modules -- this seems like a losing battle.

Comment: @Tobias, indeed, I have reason, but not of mathematical orders. As I have said, I am for instance thinking about how to talk of non commutative algebra (ring especially), to an audience lacking some concepts on modules.

Comment: @rschwieb, No I'am not afraid of it :-): I have already done this!
Abelian groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, and all the study could be done with this point of view, but there are numerous of good books on groups for themselves from "their" point of view. I am surprised that the study of noncommutative rings is not made "as long as possible" within their theory without the help of such a "big" (;-)) theory that is the one of modules...

Comment: But those books on groups do not consider just abelian groups usually. They consider arbitrary groups, which are not modules over some ring (they don't even form an abelian category).

Comment: I have nothing against commutative rings ;).

Comment: Dear @Carrérond : I think a lot of people would say that avoiding modules is awkward and of dubious value. Even theorems as elementary as the Artin-Wedderburn theorem implicitly use modules. For another thing, the ring/module relationship has a very useful analogue to the field/vector space relationship. But if you are determined to try, I won't say any more. It's difficult to contribute help when the request feels like it is doing things a hard way. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found this book of McCoy called "Rings and Ideals" (MAA, 1962) which deals with ring on more than 200 pages without using modules.
Of course, lots of material is about commutative. Let's search again !... :-)